# Meaning of specific characters in SAS documentation

Tags: syntax, sas

This snippet is from the SAS documentation website. What do the angle brackets mean in this statement? It looks like they are supposed to be ignored in actual code, meaning no extra syntax, parenthesis, etc. Is this always true? Same for the vertical bar?

```
PROC TEMPLATE;
DEFINE STYLE style-path | Base.Template.Style </ STORE=libref.template-store>;
PARENT=style-path;
NOTES "text";
CLASS style-element-name(s) <"text">
</ style-attribute-specification(s)>;
STYLE style-element-name(s) <FROM style-element-name | _SELF_ > <"text">
</ style-attribute-specification(s)>;
END;
END;
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Answer (score 1):

In the olden days, the front of each book would explain the document notations.  The code you ask about is from "[SAS® 9.4 Output Delivery System: Procedures Guide, Third Edition](https://documentation.sas.com/api/docsets/odsproc/9.4/content/odsproc.pdf?locale=en#nameddest=p1b72ff70v3obrn16aanp1r9q2bu)".  Not sure why that book does not explain or have a link to Syntax Conventions.

The SAS documentation on the Syntax Conventions used in documentation can be found in "[Syntax Conventions for the SAS Language](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n18vucblyvk64en1styw57v68shi.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)" which has this introduction:

> #### Overview of Syntax Conventions for the SAS Language
>
> SAS uses standard conventions in the documentation of syntax for SAS language elements. These conventions enable you to easily identify the components of SAS syntax. The conventions can be divided into these parts:
>
> - syntax components
> - style conventions
> - special characters
> - references to SAS libraries and external files